# How to get selected value of selection field odoo 15

Tags: python, xml, odoo, odoo-14, odoo-15

i have this selection field

```
Fam = fields.Selection(selection=[('x1','x1'),('x2','x2')])
```

i want to get the selected value of Fam selection field and write the condition if no item is selected in Fam

i tried this code

```
@api.onchange('Fam')
def _onchange_Fam(self):
    #here i want to write condition of if No item is selected in Fam selection field
    if(self.Fam == ''):
        #code
    else:
        #print the selected value
        print (dict(self._fields['Fam'].selection).get(self.Fam))
```

But i get this error :

> ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is
> required

i want to know how to print selected field and how to check if there is a selected item in the selection field

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your check should work already, but it is enough to check if the field value is `Falsy`.

If you want to have the selection value (not the key) you could use `_description_selection()` of that field, which will also handle translation of that value:

```py
@api.onchange('Fam')
def _onchange_Fam(self):
    if not self.Fam:
        # some code
    else:
        #print the selected value
        print (dict(self._fields['Fam']._description_selection(self.env)).get(self.Fam))
```